# PHP Reformat content array and Count same value

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, arraylist

I have dynamically array for example like this:

```
[{"Name":"Sutejo","status":"Overload"},{"Name":"Paiman","status":"Overload"},{"Name":"Agung Hercules","status":"Idle"},{"Name":"Heru","status":"Busy"}]
```

How should i do if want to make my array become like this ? (count if status has same value and combine to be array again)

Expected output:

```
[{"Overload":"2"},{"Idle":"1"},{"Busy":"1"}]
```

So far my code just like this:

```
public function getData(){
        $key_idle = 0;
        $key_busy = 0;
        $key_overload = 0;
        $data = $this->queries_trend->getDataCustomer();
        //print_r(json_encode($data));

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $val = $value['status'];
            if ($val == 'Idle') {
                $key_idle = $key_idle + 1;
            } elseif ($val == 'Busy') {
                $key_busy = $key_busy + 1;
            } elseif ($val == 'Overload') {
                $key_overload = $key_overload + 1;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) function:

```
$statuses = array_count_values(array_column($list, 'status'));
```